# React Router not responding to Param

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

I've been going through some other threads but have not found an answer to help me out. I'm building a very simple E-commerce website. The router has been working fine until I get to a route like `"localhost:3000/shop/1"` or `"localhost:3000/shop/2"`, where it continues to display the `<Shop />` element that I should only see on the `"localhost:3000/shop"` route instead of the `<Item />` element. While I've found a workaround, I'm confused why only the workaround is valid and would love to see if there's a way to make it work for the first way that I have it formatted.

Here's what doesn't work:

App.tsx

```
import { Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './pages/Home'
import Shop from './pages/Shop';
import Item from './pages/Item';
import CheckOut from './pages/Checkout';
import NotFound from './pages/NotFound';
import NavBar from './assets/navbar';

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Routes>
        <Route element={<NavBar />}>
          <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
          <Route path='shop/' element={<Shop />}>
            <Route path=':id' element={<Item />} />
          </Route>
          <Route path='*' element={<NotFound />} />
        </Route>
        <Route path='checkout' element={<CheckOut />} />
        <Route path='*' element={<NotFound />} />
      </Routes>
    </>
  )
}

export default App;
```

I've tried changing `<Route path='shop/' element={<Shop />}>` to `<Route path='shop' element={<Shop />}>` and still there has been no change in the functionality.

Here's what does work:

App.tsx

```
import { Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './pages/Home'
import Shop from './pages/Shop';
import Item from './pages/Item';
import CheckOut from './pages/Checkout';
import NotFound from './pages/NotFound';
import NavBar from './assets/navbar';

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Routes>
        <Route element={<NavBar />}>
          <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
          <Route path='shop' element={<Shop />} />
          <Route path='shop/:id' element={<Item />} />
          <Route path='*' element={<NotFound />} />
        </Route>
        <Route path='checkout' element={<CheckOut />} />
        <Route path='*' element={<NotFound />} />
      </Routes>
    </>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Is there a reason why one way does work and the other doesn't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If when the URL path is `"/shop/1"` or `"/shop/2"` and ***only*** the `Shop` component is still rendered then I suspect the `Shop` component is missing rendering an `Outlet` component for the nested routes it renders.

Add the missing `Outlet` to `Shop` so nested routes like `"/shop/:id"` can render their `element` content into it. This is similar what `NavBar` is doing to render the `"/"` and `"/shop"` nested routes.

Example:

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const Shop = () => {
  ... shop business logic ...

  return (
    ... Shop UI ...
    <Outlet /> // <-- nested route content rendered here
    ...
  );
};
```

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route element={<NavBar />}>
        <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
        <Route path='shop' element={<Shop />}>
          <Route path=':id' element={<Item />} /> // <-- rendered into Shop Outlet
        </Route>
      </Route>
      <Route path='checkout' element={<CheckOut />} />
      <Route path='*' element={<NotFound />} />
    </Routes>
  );
}
```

For more information and details see:

- [Layout Routes](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/concepts#layout-routes)
- [Outlets](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/concepts#outlets)

If it is the case that you want `Shop` and `Item` to each render on their own discrete routes then ***un-nest*** the `Item` route and render them as sibling routes as you do in your second code example.

Example:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route element={<NavBar />}>
        <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
        <Route path='shop'>
          <Route index element={<Shop />} />
          <Route path=':id' element={<Item />} />
        </Route>
      </Route>
      <Route path='checkout' element={<CheckOut />} />
      <Route path='*' element={<NotFound />} />
    </Routes>
  );
}
```

For more information see:

- [Index Routes](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/concepts#index-routes)

Comment: Thank you so much! Since I had Outlet in my Navbar, I didn't realize it also needed to be added to Shop as well. That solved it for me